# find the longest intersection of two integer arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this problem but don't know what's best way to solve it in term of time complexity and space complexity. 
   Suppose I have two integer arrays

```
   a={1,2,3,4,5}
   b={2,3,4,5,6}
```

and of course they not necessarily to be sorted.

So the question is how to find 2,3,4,5? It better to have some code. Thanks in advance

Comment: It indeed better to have some code!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your requirements for what should be found if the array is not sorted? Should it return the longest sorted intersection?

Comment: Please edit your problem and provide clear problem statement in your text and/or include more examples in the text, with answers; eg, for a={1,2,3,4,5}, b={2,3,1,4,5,6} and also for  a={1,3,7,5,13,13}, b={2,13,7,1,4,5,13}.

Comment: Similar request to @jwpat7: please elaborate. For example, if `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` and `b = {1, 3, 4, 5, 8}`, then do you expect the result to be `{1, 3, 4, 5}` or `{3, 4, 5}`? The first is the [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), the second is the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). There are well-known solutions to each.

Answer (score 2):

**why do we need DP here?** question says find the longest intersection, not any intersection. am i missing a point?

There are lot of solutions to this.

```
int [] a = {...}; // n elements  
int [] b = {...}; // m elements
```

You can store one array in a dictionary and for each element in the other array check the dictionary. That `O(n)`. THis will cost you more space due to dictionary. and it s not in-place

Another solution would be for each element in a, you can do a linear search on b. which is `O(n.m)`

Another would be ;if you sort both of the arrays. Then for each element in one array do a binary search in another array. You will find the intersection of two. and this will be `mlogn + nlogn` or `nlogm + mlogm`

**do we really need DP here?**

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty popular programming problem.  There is a dynamic programming approach to solving it.  You can check out more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link will solve your problem.
You have to write a **common function**  which will display common numbers in two arrays.
And it use only  **one for loop** .Thats why its complexity will be just **O(N).**

[Find common numbers.](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/135046-array-search-complexity-problem.html)

Code is in C . But i hope you can understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

At first we should sort our arrays, at second we should use binary search to finde a intersection of thise arrays.
Why? Because if we semple will searching intersection, without sort, our algorithm laboriousness will be `N^2`, but if we sort array before searching, totaly we will have `[log_2(N)N + ( N(log_2(N)) up to N^2 )]`.
My method is useful for majority of samples